# Existence of intersection curve between surfaces

Tags: multivariable-calculus, smooth-manifolds

I have a question about the existence of an intersection curve between two surfaces $ S_1, S_2 \subset \mathbb{R}^3$.

There are many methods to find this intersection curve using numerical methods such as marching methods, tracing, and so on.

But I'm curious about when and why ( if there exists ) such an intersection curve exists.

When I looked at geometric books such as differential geometry, I found no proof of my curiosity.

It looks obvious (my point of view) but I want to prove this mathematically rigorously.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thanks for your helpful comment. I edited my question.

Comment: It is not clear what are you asking. If you want to get an answer you need to pose your question accurately.

Comment: @Sasha I edited my question. Sorry for the inconvenience. I consider arbitrary surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$. I want to clarify when and why(if there exists) an intersection curve exists.

Comment: mathematically speaking, if you have two surfaces in $R^{3}$, you should write down the formula of the surface $z_{1}=f(x,y),z_{2}=g(x,y)$.

Comment: @monotoneoperator yes, i agree with you. then, intersection is written as $I = \{(x,y,z)|f(x,y)=g(x,y)=z\} $ for some functions $f, g$. But, I don't know how to clarify the condition that $I$ is an curve.

Comment: @MLATH from $f(x,y)=g(x,y)$ we can get $y=h(x)$ by implicit function theorem, and then $I=\{(x,h(x),f(x,h(x)))|x\in\ some\ interval\}$, that is to say, $I$  is a curve in $R^{3}$.

Comment: In this degree of generality this question is impossible to answer. Imagine somebody asks you "when and why an integer is prime?" What could you tell them besides the definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see why this is not obvious, consider the case of two spheres of radius one, with varying midpoints. If the midpoints are far away ($d >2$), then the intersection is empty. If $d = 2$, they intersect in a single point. If $2 > d > 0$, they intersect in a circle, so you get indeed a curve. If $d = 0$, they intersect in a full sphere.

If you allow for arbitrary surfaces, the cases might mix: They may touch at some points, intsersect in curves at other points and be locally the same somewhere else.

---

For a rigorous answer, suppose the surfaces are given by $$S_1 = \{(x,y,z) : f_1(x,y,z) = 0\}\quad \text{ and } \quad S_2 = \{(x,y,z) : f_2(x,y,z) = 0\}.$$
You want to know if the intersection $S_1 \cap S_2$ is a curve, i.e. a $1$-dimensional manifold¹. The intersection is given by
$$S_1 \cap S_2 = \{(x,y,z) : f_1(x,y,z) = 0 = f_2(x,y,z)\}.$$
By the implicit function theorem, this is a $1$-dim manifold if and only if for each point $q \in S_1 \cap S_2$ the differential matrix
$$Df(q) = \begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x}(q) & \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial y}(q) &\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial z}(q) \\
\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x}(q) & \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial y}(q) &\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial z}(q) \end{pmatrix}$$
has rank two.

*Exercise.* Calculate the differential matrix in the various cases of the example with two spheres from the beginning.

---

¹If you want to allow singular curves, things might become more complicated.